# how can I submit form without one field (no ajax)

Tags: jquery

I have a form. I would like to submit form and send all data without one input in this form with id: someField. How can I do that. My jquery code is now:

```
 $("#mForm").submit();
```

Comment: Why? Just get the server-side script not to process the field's value.

Comment: I think you can't do that. You can restrict the field in server side after submitting

Comment: okay! then what are you posting in the form? can you plz make it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the field before submitting.

```
$('#someField').remove();
$("#mForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Disabled fields in a form are not submitted.

So try to disable the input field, the one which you do not want to post.

Try something like this :

```
$('#INPUT_FIELD_ID_HERE').attr("disabled", true); 
$("#mForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the field with id  id: someField.

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

try this

```
$('#someField').remove();
$("#mForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP as server side language then you can make that field "Disabled" and hence its value will not be posted [Disable input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

```
 <input type="text" name="lname" disabled="disabled"/>
```